# Slash delete command error unknown interaction

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I need some help here I have this delete command with 2 options (amount and all)
when i call ammount it deletes the message but discord bot stays thinking and then says `app not responding`, it only works fine if i delete just 1 message. and if i use to clean all.
but if its more than 1 it does the job but throws the error in discord and in console it says `An error occurred: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction`
this is my slash command for deletion

```
@bot.tree.command(name="cleanup", description="Well... it cleans... what else do you think it does (:)")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
@app_commands.describe(all="Delete all messages in this channel",
                       amount="Delete a specific amount of messages (1 to 100)")
async def cleanup(interaction: discord.Interaction, all: bool = False, amount: int = None):
    try:
        if all:
            await interaction.channel.purge(limit=None)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"All messages in this channel have been deleted.")
        elif amount:
            if amount < 1 or amount > 100:
                await interaction.response.send_message(f"Please enter a number between 1 and 100 for the 'amount' option.")
            else:
                await interaction.channel.purge(limit=amount)
                await interaction.response.send_message(f"{amount} messages have been deleted in this channel.", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Please provide one of the options: 'all' or 'amount'.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

I tried chat gpt but it keeps throwing old discord_slash_commands deprecated version commands haha
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to respond within 3 seconds, no matter what. You're purging before responding, so you probably exceed the deadline.

If you have to do something slow in an app command, you can use `defer()`, and `followup` to respond later on.

P.s. `all` is a built-in keyword in Python, as the syntax highlighting (and your Linter) suggest. Don't shadow built-ins.